# How can I make script file for making scylladb keyspace and table on running docker container

Tags: docker, docker-compose, scylla

I'm trying to make keyspace and table while making scyllaDB container, but I'm not able to understand how I can make .sh file and how I can use it in docker-compose while creating scyllaDB container.

docker-compose file:

```
version: "3"

services:

  scyllaDB-node1:
    container_name: scyllaDB-node1
    image: scylladb/scylla:5.1.0
    restart: always
    command: --seeds=scyllaDB-node1,scyllaDB-node2 --smp 1 --memory 750M --overprovisioned 1 --api-address 0.0.0.0
    networks:
      web1:

  scyllaDB-node2:
    container_name: scyllaDB-node2
    image: scylladb/scylla:5.1.0
    restart: always
    command: --seeds=scyllaDB-node1,scyllaDB-node2 --smp 1 --memory 750M --overprovisioned 1 --api-address 0.0.0.0
    networks:
      web1:

  scyllaDB-node3:
    container_name: scyllaDB-node3
    image: scylladb/scylla:5.1.0
    restart: always
    command: --seeds=scyllaDB-node1,scyllaDB-node2 --smp 1 --memory 750M --overprovisioned 1 --api-address 0.0.0.0
    networks:
      web1:

networks:
  web1:
    driver: bridge
```

Kindly help me in that.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using a schema migration tool - ideally you will want to have a separate container (let's call it "*app*") which will verify whether your cluster is up and readily available (remember that schema changes during topology changes are strongly discouraged).

Your "*app*" container will have a script as the `entrypoint` which will execute the CQL statements you want.

For example, you may add the following lines to your `docker-compose.yaml`:

```
app:
build: .
container_name: app
hostname: app
```

And that should be enough for you to build and run an "*app*" container from a *Dockerfile* defined within your root.

You may want to check [this example](https://github.com/fee-mendes/rust-driver-example/tree/main/docker-compose) which demonstrates how to bring up a ScyllaDB cluster and an app container to run a Rust program alongside it. This approach is covered in the [Build Low-Latency Applications in Rust](https://resources.scylladb.com/videos/build-low-latency-applications-in-rust-on-scylladb) workshop.

Comment: Thank You for your response @Felipe Mendes. I'm trying to do this, but still there is no delay. Kindly check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76061506/how-to-check-whether-3-node-scylladb-cluster-is-up-or-not-before-running-other-c .