# How to check whether 3 node scylladb cluster is up or not before running other container in docker compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, scylla

I want to run .sh file as entrypoint in docker compose, but before this I want 3 node scylladb cluster up. For that I've to wait until 3 node cluster is up.

docker compose:

```
version: "3"

services:
    
  scyllaDB-node1:
    container_name: scyllaDB-node1
    image: scylladb/scylla:5.1.0
    hostname: scyllaDB-node1
    restart: always
    command: --seeds=scyllaDB-node1,scyllaDB-node2 --smp 1 --memory 750M --overprovisioned 1 --api-address 0.0.0.0
    volumes:
      - "./scylla/scylla.yaml:/etc/scylla/scylla.yaml"
      - "./scylla/cassandra-rackdc.properties.dc3:/etc/scylla/cassandra-rackdc.properties"

  scyllaDB-node2:
    container_name: scyllaDB-node2
    image: scylladb/scylla:5.1.0
    hostname: scyllaDB-node2
    restart: always
    command: --seeds=scyllaDB-node1,scyllaDB-node2 --smp 1 --memory 750M --overprovisioned 1 --api-address 0.0.0.0
    volumes:
      - "./scylla/scylla.yaml:/etc/scylla/scylla.yaml"
      - "./scylla/cassandra-rackdc.properties.dc3:/etc/scylla/cassandra-rackdc.properties"

  scyllaDB-node3:
    container_name: scyllaDB-node3
    image: scylladb/scylla:5.1.0
    hostname: scyllaDB-node3
    restart: always
    command: --seeds=scyllaDB-node1,scyllaDB-node2 --smp 1 --memory 750M --overprovisioned 1 --api-address 0.0.0.0
    volumes:
      - "./scylla/scylla.yaml:/etc/scylla/scylla.yaml"
      - "./scylla/cassandra-rackdc.properties.dc3:/etc/scylla/cassandra-rackdc.properties"
      
  init-schema:
    container_name: init-schema
    build: .
    restart: always
    entrypoint: ["/wrapper.sh"]
    volumes:
      - ./wrapper.sh:/wrapper.sh
```

I'm applying logic that, inside 'init-schema' container I'm building Dockerfile, which will check whether scylladb cluster is up or not.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM scylladb/scylla:5.1.0

WORKDIR /usr/src

COPY ./check_cluster_healthy.sh .

RUN chmod +x /usr/src/check_cluster_healthy.sh

CMD ["/usr/src/check_cluster_healthy.sh"]
```

check_cluster_healthy.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash

while true; do
   (echo >/dev/tcp/scyllaDB-node1/9042) &>/dev/null 
   if [ "$?" == "0" ]; then
      echo "scyllaDB-node1 is ready" 
      SCYLLA1_READY="true"
   else
      echo "Waiting for scyllaDB-node1 CQL port"
      SCYLLA1_READY="false"
   fi

   (echo >/dev/tcp/scyllaDB-node2/9042) &>/dev/null 
   if [ "$?" == "0" ]; then
      echo "scyllaDB-node2 is ready"
      SCYLLA2_READY="true"
   else
      echo "Waiting for scyllaDB-node2 CQL port"
      SCYLLA2_READY="false"
   fi

   (echo >/dev/tcp/scyllaDB-node3/9042) &>/dev/null 
   if [ "$?" == "0" ]; then
      echo "scyllaDB-node3 is ready"
      SCYLLA3_READY="true"
   else
      echo "Waiting for scyllaDB-node3 CQL port"
      SCYLLA3_READY="false"
   fi

   if [ "$SCYLLA1_READY" == "$SCYLLA2_READY" ]; then
      if [ "$SCYLLA2_READY" == "$SCYLLA3_READY" ]; then
         if [ "$SCYLLA1_READY" == "true" ]; then
            echo "ScyllaDB is up and available. You are ready to go!"
            break
         fi
      fi
   fi
   sleep 5
done

sleep 36000
```

But still its not working, when I run 'docker compose up -d' it immediately run all four containers. There is no delay. Help me in that. Any help is appreciated.

**UPDATE:**
Instead of making separate Dockerfile simply I've added sleep in wrapper.sh file.

wrapper.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash

sleep 180

CQL="CREATE KEYSPACE IF NOT EXISTS test WITH REPLICATION = {'class': 'NetworkTopologyStrategy', 'DC3': 3}; CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test.books (book_id int PRIMARY KEY, book_name text, genre text, price double, issue_date text, return_date text, fine double);"
echo "Executing: $CQL"

until cqlsh -e "$CQL"; do
    echo "Unavailable: sleeping"
    sleep 10
done &

exec /docker-entrypoint.py "$@"
```

Updated docker-compose:

```
version: "3"

services:
    
  scyllaDB-node1:
    container_name: scyllaDB-node1
    image: scylladb/scylla:5.1.0
    hostname: scyllaDB-node1
    restart: always
    command: --seeds=scyllaDB-node1,scyllaDB-node2 --smp 1 --memory 750M --overprovisioned 1 --api-address 0.0.0.0
    volumes:
      - "./scylla/scylla.yaml:/etc/scylla/scylla.yaml"
      - "./scylla/cassandra-rackdc.properties.dc3:/etc/scylla/cassandra-rackdc.properties"

  scyllaDB-node2:
    container_name: scyllaDB-node2
    image: scylladb/scylla:5.1.0
    hostname: scyllaDB-node2
    restart: always
    command: --seeds=scyllaDB-node1,scyllaDB-node2 --smp 1 --memory 750M --overprovisioned 1 --api-address 0.0.0.0
    volumes:
      - "./scylla/scylla.yaml:/etc/scylla/scylla.yaml"
      - "./scylla/cassandra-rackdc.properties.dc3:/etc/scylla/cassandra-rackdc.properties"

  scyllaDB-node3:
    container_name: scyllaDB-node3
    image: scylladb/scylla:5.1.0
    hostname: scyllaDB-node3
    restart: always
    command: --seeds=scyllaDB-node1,scyllaDB-node2 --smp 1 --memory 750M --overprovisioned 1 --api-address 0.0.0.0
    volumes:
      - "./scylla/scylla.yaml:/etc/scylla/scylla.yaml"
      - "./scylla/cassandra-rackdc.properties.dc3:/etc/scylla/cassandra-rackdc.properties"
      
  init-schema:
    container_name: init-schema
    image: scylladb/scylla:5.1.0
    restart: always
    entrypoint: ["/wrapper.sh"]
    volumes:
      - ./wrapper.sh:/wrapper.sh
```

Now delay is working fine, but still keyspace and table is not creating. Gives following error:

```
init-schema     | Executing: CREATE KEYSPACE IF NOT EXISTS test WITH REPLICATION = {'class': 'NetworkTopologyStrategy', 'DC3': 3}; CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test.books (book_id int PRIMARY KEY, book_name text, genre text, price double, issue_date text, return_date text, fine double);
init-schema     | running: (['/opt/scylladb/scripts/scylla_dev_mode_setup', '--developer-mode', '1'],)
init-schema     | Connection error: ('Unable to connect to any servers', {'127.0.0.1': error(111, "Tried connecting to [('127.0.0.1', 9042)]. Last error: Connection refused")})
```